# Нужно написать код для замены пропусков с условиями

Tags: python, pandas

Ребята, помогите. Я новичок. Надо решить такой вопрос. Есть пропуски в файле csv в столбце Year_of_Release

| Name. | Platform | Year_of_Release | Genre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Madden NFL 2004 | PS2. |  | Sports |
| Madden NFL 2004 | XB. | 2003.0. | Sports |
| Madden NFL 2004 | GC. | 2003.0. | Sports |
| Madden NFL 2004 | GBA. | 2003.0. | Sports |

Как написать код так чтобы пропуск заполнялся данными если они соответствуют той же Name + Genre?

Пробовал так
data.loc[data['year_of_release'] == 555, 'year_of_release'] = data.loc[data['year_of_release'] == 555, 'name']
Но он заполняет именами, а не годом.

```py
import pandas as pd

pth1 = '/content/General project_1.csv'
pth2 = '/datasets/games.csv'
try:
  data = pd.read_csv(pth2)
except:
  data = pd.read_csv(pth1)
else:
     print('Что-то не так')
data.columns = data.columns.str.lower()
data[['year_of_release']] = data[['year_of_release']].fillna(555)
data.loc[data['year_of_release'] == 555, 'name'] = data.loc[data['year_of_release'] == 555, 'year_of_release']
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `Пробовал так` может добавите немного кода, как вы именно пытались заполнить? Как файл загружаете в программу? Много вопросов, а ответа нет.

Comment: data.loc[data['year_of_release'] == 555, 'year_of_release'] = data.loc[data['year_of_release'] == 555, 'name']

Это сам код. А файл загружаю так

import os

pth1 = '/datasets/calls.csv'
pth2 = '/content/calls.csv'

if os.path.exists(pth1):
    query_1 = pd.read_csv(pth1)
elif os.path.exists(pth2):
    query_1 = pd.read_csv(pth2)
else:
    print('Something is wrong')

Comment: Пропуск я заменил маркером 555. Их (пропусков)  в общем файле около 300.

Comment: Добавляйте весь код непосредственно в вопрос, вы можете его редактировать. Код в комментариях часто бесполезен, потому что он не может быть отформатирован, а в питоне без форматирования теряется часть информации.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сгруппировать по двум полям и применить методы `.bfill()` и `.ffill()` для заполнения пустот назад и вперед последними (перед пустотами) непустыми значениями из столбца.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Madden NFL 2004', 'Madden NFL 2004', 'Madden NFL 2004', 'Madden NFL 2004','Madden NFL 2004', 'Madden NFL 2004', 'Madden NFL 2004', 'Madden NFL 2004'],
                   'Platform': ['PS2.', 'XB.', 'GC.', 'GBA.', 'PS2.', 'XB.', 'GC.', 'GBA.'],
                   'Year_of_Release': [np.nan, '2003.0.', '2003.0.', '2003.0.', np.nan, '2004.0.', '2004.0.',np.nan],
                   'Genre': ['Sports', 'Sports', 'Sports', 'Sports', 'Action', 'Action', 'Action', 'Action']})
df['Year_of_Release'] = df.groupby(['Name','Genre'])['Year_of_Release'].bfill().ffill()
print(df)
```

```
              Name Platform Year_of_Release   Genre
0  Madden NFL 2004     PS2.         2003.0.  Sports
1  Madden NFL 2004      XB.         2003.0.  Sports
2  Madden NFL 2004      GC.         2003.0.  Sports
3  Madden NFL 2004     GBA.         2003.0.  Sports
4  Madden NFL 2004     PS2.         2004.0.  Action
5  Madden NFL 2004      XB.         2004.0.  Action
6  Madden NFL 2004      GC.         2004.0.  Action
7  Madden NFL 2004     GBA.         2004.0.  Action
```

Comment: Метод хороший, но, к сожалению, не для моего случая...У меня нет уверенности, что перед или после пропуска нужное мне значение. Самый оптимальный вариант это чтобы пропуск заполнялся данными если они соответствуют той же Name + Genre. Но я не знаю как этого добиться...

Comment: Это работает именно так, как вы описали. За счёт группировки значения для заполнения ограничены сочетанием имени и жанра

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь. Пойду пробовать.

Comment: Могли бы Вы помочь разобраться дальше в этом вопросе.
Я код скопировал и он работает, пропуски ушли. Но я так понимаю этот код для объекта сериес, я библиотеку не создавал, я применяю к датасету, путем добавления квадратных скобок, но он мне выдет ошибку.

Comment: dataх[['year_of_release']] = data.groupby([['name','genre']])[['year_of_release']].bfill().ffill()

Comment: ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Comment: Все, все отлично! Ошибка в названиях была. Все работает!